# How to use Http:fake() with Job

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to write a test with Http::fake() but my original Http::post is in a job.
I am not sure how to test this can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

You could test the job itself, separately from wherever it's normally dispatched.

```php
// tests/Feature/SomeControllerTest.php
public function test_controller_dispatches_job()
{
    Bus::fake();

    $this->get('/some-route')->assertSuccessful();

    Bus::assertDispatched(App\Jobs\SomeJob::class);
}

// tests/Unit/SomeJobTest.php
public function test_job_makes_http_call()
{
    Http::fake();

    $job = app(App\Jobs\SomeJob::class);

    $job->handle();

    Http::assetSent(function (Request $request) {
        return $request->url() == 'http://example.com';
    });
}
```